# How to reset an object to its original value and maintain binding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I have a service which has a complex object which comes from an API, e.g.

```
{
    name: "Foo",
    addr: {
        street: "123 Acacia Ave",
        zip: "10010"
    }
}
```

I store it in myService.address and its initial value in another variable using

```
myService.originalAddr = angular.copy(myService.addr);
```

so I can reset a form to the initial value if needed.

In my directive's controller I inject the service and bind a scope property to myService.addr

```
$scope.addr = myService.addr;
```

...as I understand it, this should set up two way binding.

When, in another directive, I run a function:

```
$scope.reset = function(){
    myService.addr = angular.copy(myService.originalAddr);
}
```

This works as expected and myService.addr is reset to the initial value. However, the values I have bound in my form are not reset, and $scope.addr stays as it was edited. I have been using

```
<input type="text" ng-bind="addr.street"/>
```

and have also tried

```
<input type="text" ng-model="addr.street"/>
```

But the values in the form remain whatever they were edited to be and aren't reset. It seems the angular.copy is disconnecting the binding. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: code and  description, much better than words.. please improve your question

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem should be:

```
$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.addr = angular.copy(myService.originalAddr);
}
```